# Castle Windsor - not sure where to release transients created using "container.Resolve"

Tags: castle-windsor, signalr

A little background relevant to my problem:- I'm learning to use SignalR, which is a client-server RPC framework. On the server-side you write one or more "hub" classes which expose methods that can be called remotely, a bit like a web service. When a message arrives, SignalR instantiates the appropriate hub class to handle that message, but for this to work hub classes must have a parameterless constructor.

In the real world, a hub class is likely to need dependencies. Fortunately SignalR lets you replace its default "dependency resolver", which I've done. There are numerous (almost identical) samples of SignalR Castle Windsor resolvers (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10507894/integrating-castle-windsor-with-signalr-how-should-i-approach-this)), but they all rely on calling the Windsor container's `Resolve()` method. My understanding of Windsor is that you must "release what you explicitly resolve", but I can't see where I could achieve this.

Note that the hubs are registered as transients, while dependencies may be a mixture of transients and singletons.

I thought about releasing a hub's dependencies in its `Dispose()` method, but this feels wrong - the hub would need access to the Windsor container; also the hub needs to know which dependencies are transient, and only attempt to release those.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO you are bitten by the fact that the signal R dependency resolver fails to implement a Destroy method for releasing the hubs.

I agree that implementing the release of the components in the Hub's dispose method would get rather ugly. To release the hub from windsor the hub would need to call release on the container which in turn would then call the dispose again on the hub.

I think you're best bet would be to create an windsor interceptor for the hub, which will intercept the dispose call on the hub. This way only the interceptor needs to know about the container and you should be able to dispose you component.

You might need some logic in your interceptor to determine whether dispose is called from SignalR or from then windsor container. (ie if called from SignalR call Windsor release, otherwise proceed). You might do this by using e.g Thread local storage.

Comment: I don't think there's going to be an elegant solution to this! My concern that a hub is instantiated to serve each method invoke, so there's potential for memory issues if things aren't being resolved. I wonder if it would be easier to register the hubs as singletons instead? I understand SignalR calls the hub's Dispose() after the method has completed, so as long as I'm not doing anything in there, I think I should be okay? (I'm using self-hosting, not IIS if that makes a difference).

Comment: I'm not really familiar with SignalR, however in general I would assume that an object will no longer be use able after a dispose. If you would switch to singletons, can you be sure that you will never need two instances of the Hub at the same time ?