# Self-Hosted SignalR app refusing CORS requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr, cors

I am working on an MVC 5 application that uses a windows service to perform some processing; I am using signal R so that I can show if the windows service is working on the UI and also allow the user to manually start processing (as opposed to running on a schedule).

On the server side I have the following config:

```
public class SignalRStartup
{
    public static IAppBuilder App = null;

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Map("/signalr", map =>
        {
            map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);

            var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
            {
                EnableDetailedErrors = true,
            };

            map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
        });
    }
}
```

Which is used like so:

```
SignalR = WebApp.Start<SignalRStartup>(_settings.LoaderServiceUrl);
```

Right now the loader service url is: `http://localhost:8080`

Then on the client side:

```
var adminHubProxy = $.connection.adminHub;
adminHubProxy.client.updateProcessing = function(status) {
    if (status === true) {
        $('#processing').show();
    } else {
        $('#processing').hide();
    }
};

$.connection.hub.url = 'http://localhost:8080/signalr';
$.connection.hub.start();

$('#startProcessingLink').on('click', function() {
    adminHubProxy.server.startProcessing();
});
```

And if it matters the code that includes the generated proxy:

```
<script src="http://localhost:8080/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

So the problem I'm having is that when I trigger the startProcessing function the server throws back this error message:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/signalr/send?transport=serverSentEvents&connectionTok…Pp7JqCJOnkJEA%3D%3D&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22adminhub%22%7D%5D. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
```

From all the reading I've done my configuration should be resolving this issue by allowing all CORS requests but it isn't and I can't see why.

**Edit**
After some more debugging I pulled up the details of the response on the negotiate call and am seeing the following headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost
```

I'm not sure why the credentials header is being added at all, but the origin header again makes me believe that this should be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem, first off the error message has absolutely nothing to do with what is going on.

TL;DR;
The problem was that the AdminHub could not be resolved on the server side because of my dependency injection setup

I am using Castle Windsor for dependency injection and originally the AdminHub looked like this:

```
 public class AdminHub : Hub
    {
        private readonly IMyService _myService;

        public AdminHub(IMyService myService)
        {
            _myService= myService;
            _myService.OnProcessingUpdate += (sender, args) => UpdateProcessingStatus();
        }

        public void UpdateProcessingStatus()
        {
            Clients.All.updateProcessing(_myService.IsProcessing);
        }

        public void GetProcessingStatus()
        {
            Clients.Caller.updateProcessing(_myService.IsProcessing);
        }

        public void StartProcessing()
        {
            _myService.Process();
        }
    }
```

The default dependency resolver cannot resolve this as it requires a parameterless constructor. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10549707/1618236) both served to point out what was happening and provide the basis for a solution.